# How to create a value from a nil pointer

Tags: go, pointers

In Go 1.19, consider these definitions:

```
type A struct{}
type B struct{}

type Field interface {
    *A | *B
}

type Person[T Field] struct {
    field T
}
```

Given a nil `Field`, can I dynamically create its underlying value?

```
func (p Person[T]) do() {
  if p.field == nil {

    // Can I make a value here that will be *A or *B dynamically depending on T?
    // Something that would be equivalent to new(A) or new(B)
    p.field = ?

  }
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://go.dev/play/p/06OzoQ3jqZs) what you're asking for? Or is `*A | *B` a requirement?

Comment: If the types in the `Field` union MUST be pointers, then you'll have to use `reflect` since it's not possible to dereference a pointer __type__ (only a pointer __value__ can be dereferenced), which means doing something like `new(*T)` is not possible.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks.  `*A | *B` is a simplification, but the type is indeed an interface.  The actual generic is `Person[T proto.Message]`, where the generic can be a pointer to any protobuf.   Could you say more about how `reflect` might help please?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/GtnL3WcnB1E (note that the logic changes if the type _argument_ isn't a pointer).

Comment: @mkopriva that worked!  Seems it's time for me to learn what reflect is all about.  If you'd like, please post as an answer with explanations around what each step does so I can accept your answer.  Either way, you've unblocked me: thanks!

Comment: You can do this without reflect if you use `A | B` instead of `*A | *B`

Comment: @BurakSerdar I think my example just added to the confusion.  It's actually not `*A|*B`, but `proto.Message`.  It's an interface.

@mkopriva I spoke a little too soon.  I still need to figure out how to check for `nil` because `if p.field == nil` errors with something like "mismatched types T and untyped nil"

Comment: @BeetleJuice take a look all the available methods in `reflect`, for example to check for `nil` you can try [`reflect.ValueOf(p.field).IsNil()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.21.0#Value.IsNil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
func (p Person[T]) do() {
    if p.field == nil {
        // assuming T is a pointer type, e.g. *A
        pp := new(T)             // initialize an instance of **A
        rt := reflect.TypeOf(pp) // get the reflect.Type representation of **A
        rt = rt.Elem()           // get the reflect.Type representation of *A
        rt = rt.Elem()           // get the reflect.Type representation of A
        rv := reflect.New(rt)    // initialize reflect.Value representation of *A
        v := rv.Interface()      // get the interface{}(*A) instance from reflect.Value
        t := v.(T)               // type assert the interface's dynamic type
        p.field = t
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/GtnL3WcnB1E

---

For more see the docs:

- [`reflect.TypeOf`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.21.0#TypeOf) get type info of specified value
- [`reflect.Type.Elem`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.21.0#Type.Elem) get the type's element type
- [`reflect.New`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.21.0#New) return a pointer to zero value of specified type
- [`reflect.Value.Interface`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.21.0#Value.Interface) return value as interface{}
- [`v.(T)`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) type assertion

Comment: Instead of `rt := reflect.TypeOf(new(T)).Elem().Elem()` you may simply do `rt := reflect.TypeOf(p.field).Elem()`. Less allocation, shorter, cleaner code and more efficient.